# Keycloak Environment Variables Not Working

Tags: keycloak

I would like to specify the database for Keycloak to use.

I've found [this](https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config) which specifies the parameters and `environment variables` that can be used. `KC_DB` should be available for setting the vendor. E.g. `mysql`.

I create a `Dockerfile` to create my image.

```
FROM  bitnami/keycloak:18

EXPOSE 80
```

I then run the image using this.

```
docker run --name keycloak -e KC_DB=mysql -p 8080:80 keycloak
```

**Logs**

```
PS D:\Projects\keycloak> docker run --name keycloak -e KC_DB=mysql -p 8080:80 keycloak
keycloak 23:48:07.88 
keycloak 23:48:07.88 Welcome to the Bitnami keycloak container
keycloak 23:48:07.88 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
keycloak 23:48:07.89 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
keycloak 23:48:07.89 
keycloak 23:48:07.89 INFO  ==> ** Starting keycloak setup **
keycloak 23:48:07.90 INFO  ==> Validating settings in KEYCLOAK_* env vars...
keycloak 23:48:07.91 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to PostgreSQL server postgresql...
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:51615->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:57656->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:41930->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:48347->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:43866->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:49390->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:39474->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:46428->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:59657->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
cannot resolve host "postgresql": lookup postgresql on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:56871->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
```

I've tried using the `KC_DB_HOST` and multiple other environment variables but they don't seem to be picked up. I've tried this with `Keycloak 19` too.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consult that to the docker image creator you're are using, here is the github reference [link](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-keycloak) maybe they able to create another docker image using mysql, so far the documentation from the github repository the image requires you to use postgresql database.

Comment: I didn't think about the different images requiring different environment variables! I do want to use postgres so this image will be fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this image has a built-in default variable for the host. If you want you can just add 'postgresql' to your hosts to be recognized as some other ip. You can do it the following way:

first you might want to check which hosts you already have:

`type C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

it will print something like

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

then using any editor add new line containing

`<DESIRED-HOST> postgresql`

in case your postgres is running locally just put 127.0.0.1 as host